# Open a set of URLs in IE if another URL is open using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

On the second run of this script, I can open Microsoft and Yahoo if I first close Bing; how can I open those sites without first closing Bing? The error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Navigate2'.
+                 $ie.Navigate2 <<<< ("www.microsoft.com", $navOpenInNewTab);
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Navigate2:String) [], Runtime Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Why does it fail when I have Bing and Google open, but not when I have Google open?

```
# Set BrowserNavConstants to open URL in new tab
# Full list of BrowserNavConstants: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360.aspx
$navOpenInNewTab = 0x800;
$navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;

$ie = $null
if (Get-Process iexplore -ea silentlycontinue | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""}) {
    $ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" }
} else {
    $ie = New-Object -COM "InternetExplorer.Application"
    sleep -milliseconds 50
    $ie.visible = $true
}

$today = (get-date).DayOfWeek
switch ($today) { 
    "Someday" {
        $ie.Navigate("www.bing.com");
        $ie.Navigate2("www.yahoo.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab); break
    }
    default {
        $google = $false
        # Check if Google open
        foreach ($tab in $ie) {
            if ($tab.LocationURL.Contains("google"))
            { $google = $true; break }
        }
        # If Google open on second run, open Microsoft and Yahoo
        if ($google) {
            $ie.Navigate2("www.microsoft.com", $navOpenInNewTab);
            $ie.Navigate2("www.yahoo.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
        } else {
            # On first run, open Bing and Google 
            $ie.Navigate("www.bing.com");
            $ie.Navigate2("www.google.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
        }
        break
    }
}

# Cleanup
'ie' | ForEach-Object {Remove-Variable $_ -Force}
```

Comment: I am disappointed. You more or less just take what you got as answer to your last question, add a new twist to it, and ask again. That's not how this site is supposed to operate.

Comment: I thought I was being helpful by creating a new question to address a separate, specific issue.

Comment: But if I close Bing, such that only one tab is open, the script succeeds; how do I need to change that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be, that the script fails to find (the right) open IE instance on the second run. Debug the Script in the PowerShell ISE (or the PowerShell PowerGUI) and set a breakpoint at `$ie=(New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? {$_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer"}`

Run the following command in the interactive PowerShell Window below: `(New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | Select-Object { $_.Name  }`

Do you get something like this as output?

```
File Explorer    
Internet Explorer  
Internet Explorer  
Internet Explorer  
Internet Explorer
```

Try to adjust your code as needed when your IE windows have different Names.
The following code works on my machine: I select just the first IE instance (otherwise you get problems since you open multiple sites).

```
    ...
    # If Google open on second run, open Microsoft and Yahoo
    if ($google) {
        sleep -milliseconds 50
        $ie[0].Navigate2("www.microsoft.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
        sleep -milliseconds 50
        $ie[0].Navigate2("www.yahoo.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
    } else { ...
```

Comment: I get `Windows Explorer` as output. If I add `| Select-Object -First` I get `Missing an argument for parameter 'First'.`